# Doctrine selects float value from database without decimal place

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, precision

I'm creating a doctrince instance like this

```
$dbalConfig = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
$dbal = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($dbalConn, $dbalConfig);
```

The dbalConfig is just mysql connection settings + setting charset to utf-8

When I now execute a query:

```
$sql = "SELECT price FROM products";
$stmt = $dbal->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$products = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

and dump the results

```
var_dump($products);
```

I'm getting all values like this

```
[1]=>
array(1) {
["price"]=>
float(17)
```

However, in the database the value is stored as a float like this `17.90`

What would I need to get the data in the correct format? I can't change the column type from float to something else in the database, because it doesn't belong to me. Is it somehow possible to get the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. The problem was, that I'm a German user. Hehe, that's not exactly the problem but it has something to do with it.

The site I'm using has `LC_NUMERIC` set to `de_DE.UTF-8`. When changing it to `en_US.UTF-8` it works without any problems.

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC , 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

Seems like the localization was just "wrong".

But! Isn't there a way to convert the US format to the German format? Because I don't really think that it would be the correct way to simply change the `LC_NUMERIC` because of the data I'm recieving, right? This sounds like a quick and dirty solution